# Vertically align text in center next to image

Tags: html, image, vertical-alignment

I am building my wife's business website at invisionbilling.com and I am having difficulties aligning the text beside an image in the center. It seems like a pretty simple concept but I just can't get it to work. What is wrong with my html?

```html
<span style="font-size: 24pt; line-height: 40px; display: inline-block;">
    <img src="http://invisionbilling.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Home-Photo-1-300x180.jpg" alt="" width="500" height="299" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-106" style="float: right; margin-left: 25px; vertical-align: middle;" />InVision Billing Solutions specializes in medical 
    practices maximizing their revenue through accurate claim 
    submission and prompt payment posting.</span>
```

Comment: Beside an image to the left... right.. top or bottom?

Comment: In this case the text is to the left of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox, and what you've got with a few tweaks works...

```html
<div style="width:100%;margin:auto;">
  <div style="float:left; width:50%;position:relative;">
     <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;height:299px">
      InVision Billing Solutions specializes in medical 
      practices maximizing their revenue through accurate claim 
      submission and prompt payment posting.
     </div>
  </div>
  <div>
      <img src="http://invisionbilling.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Home-Photo-1-300x180.jpg" alt="" width="500" height="299" style="float: right; width:50%;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Vertical Centering: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/